Q about pointers and arrays in C
I was going over some statements for pointers in C on how to iterate through an array (A[]) starting at i = 1. I was able to understand why the following works:
int* B = A; printf("%d\n", B[i - 1]);

but when I saw that this one worked as well I got confused.
int* B = (&A)[0]; printf("%d\n", B[i - 1]);

Could someone explain the logic behind (&A)[0]?
I was thinking (&A) gets the address for A, let's say 0x8000, but I am not sure what [0] would do to an address.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/62576

Does this answer your question? With arrays, why is it the case that a[5] == 5[a]?

I looked over the linked article, are you saying that despite the (&A) being in parentheses, (&A)[0] the same as &(A[0]) or &(A+0)?

@Fe2O3: if i is larger than 0, then the B[i - 1] is valid as long as i is not so great that it passes the upper array bound.  If i was zero or negative, then you'd be correct about it accessing the array out of bounds.

Sorry, I should have made it more clear. The index, i, starts at 1, which means i-1 = 0 so B[0]. I will rewrite it to make it more clear i = 1. (

@Fe203: I am sorry for the confusion. My professor was the one who decided to index at 1. I would have preferred it started at 0 myself, as that's how I am used to it as well. Next time, I will make the decision to reindex anything  to 0 before posting to make things simpler and others can understand without having to read everything

@AmyGregg Type [c] "array" "indexing" "pointer" into the "Search Box" at the top of the page... There are over 1000 existing Q&A's found with those search terms. You'll be the pointer/array expert in your class once you've sifted through the first dozen-or-so of those... Best wishes... (You'll also have gained better SO Search Skills than most.)

If you have int A[10];, the type of &A is int (*)[10] — a pointer to an array of 10 int.  The type of &A[0] is int *.  The type of (&A)[0] is int [10].  You can play with code to get results like this: sizeof(A) = 40 — sizeof(&A) = 8 — sizeof(&A[0]) = 8 — sizeof((&A)[0]) = 40.

The array index operator [] is really a shorthand for pointer arithmetic and dereferencing.  An expression of the form E1[E2] is exactly equivalent to *((E1) + (E2)).  So this:
(&A)[0]

Is exactly the same as:
*(&A + 0)

Which can be simplified to:
*&A

And since address-of and dereference effectively cancel each other out, this is the same as just:
A


Note that this correspondence is so exact that even something seemingly nonsensical like 5[array] is legal, and you will see that kind of construction in certain obfuscated code games.

Thank you! This is what I was looking for. My professor was the one who gave us these convoluted problems with tricky phrasing so I get caught up. Thanks for the thorough explanation!
